# String Method (python) - sorting letters of a sentence

Tags: python, string, sorting

Trying to sort letters of the sentence below (not in place) and print out.

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

so far this is what I've got and trying to figure out how to get it without the blank spaces at the beginning.  Also, capital 'T' is at the front.  Should it not be beside lower-case 't'?  How would I do that?  I got the `print(''.join(sorted(a)))` line through search and figured that worked but want to understand the how/why.  Any help is appreciated.

INPUT

```
a = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

print(''.join(sorted(a)))
```

OUTPUT

```
    Tabcdeeefghhijklmnoooopqrrstuuvwxyz
```

Comment: `sort()` sorts the list in ASCIIbetical order rather than actual alphabetical order. This means uppercase letters come before lowercase letters. `print(''.join(sorted(a.lower())).strip())` would fix it if you're not too attached to your capital T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character code for letter `T` is lower than character code for letter `t`, so it's before in the sorted string.

To have uppercase letters on the back, you can do:

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

s = "".join(sorted(s, key=lambda k: (k.isupper(), k)))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
        abcdeeefghhijklmnoooopqrrstuuvwxyzT
```

---

EDIT: If you want result `...stTu..`:

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

s = "".join(sorted(s, key=lambda k: (k.lower(), k.isupper())))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
        abcdeeefghhijklmnoooopqrrstTuuvwxyz
```

---

Note: To get rid of whitespaces, you can use `str.strip()` afterwards.

Comment: They want `stTu`, not all uppercase at the end.

Comment: THANK YOU!! It worked!  Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove the blanks from `a` with

`c for c in a if c != ' '`

2. The default sorting of characters uses their character codes, and all the uppercase Latin letters have lower codes in ASCII and Unicode than the lowercase characters. You can use `key=str.lower` to convert to lowercase when comparing.

```
print(''.join(sorted(c for c in a if c != ' '), key = str.lower))
```